# MDB2/MySQL, multiple connections

Tags: php, mysql, mdb2

I have a script that for the most part interacts with one mysql database.

However, when a certain function is called, I am now wanting to do an `if{}` and in the case of `true` connect to another mysql database and update a table. After this, other queries will be run on the original database.

What's the proper and most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is't the way below?

```
//do something with original db
$conn->query(...);
...
if (...) {
   // do someting with another db
   $another_conn->query(...);
   ...
}
$conn->query(...);
...
```

Comment: yep, this seems to work: ` if($this == 1){
    $db =& MDB2::factory('mysql://host...');
    $db->setFetchMode(MDB2_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);     
    $message =& $db->query("UPDATE....");       
   }`